# Use a trigger to get a value

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get data via AJAX when the select is changed, which is why I used `.trigger()`.

However, it does not seem to be working. I can get the data smoothly from the database then pass it via AJAX to item-type.

Here it is.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Coupon Protoype</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coupon.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-wrap">

            <section class="wrap-form">
                <label for="item-types">Item Types</label><select id="item-types"></select>
                <label for="item-list">Items</label><select id="item-list"></select>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Check Code" id="input-code"/>
                <input type="button" id="button-check" value="Check"/>
            </section>

            <section class="output-wrap">
                <label>Coupon Code:</label> <label id="coupon-code"></label>

            </section>

        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/coupon.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    function get_items_type(){

        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'coupon-functions.php',
                dataType:'json',
                data:{'switch-num':'1'},
            success:function(data){

                if(data.error){

                    alert(data.error);
                }
                    var html = '';
                  $.each(data, function(i, item) {       
                            html += "<option value="+data[i].item_type_id+">"+data[i].item_type+"</option>";
                    });

                   $('#item-types').append(html);
            }
        })
    }
```

/this line is what im saying       $("#item-types").on("change",function(){

```
        var item_type_id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'coupon-functions.php',
                dataType:'json',
                data:{'switch-num':'2','item_type_id':item_type_id},
            success:function(data){

                if(data.error){

                    alert(data.error);
                }
                    var items = '';

                     $('#item-list').html("");

                  $.each(data, function(i, item) {       
                            items += "<option value="+data[i].item_id+">"+data[i].item_name+"</option>";
                    });

                   $('#item-list').append(items);
            }
        })


    });

    $("#item-types").trigger("change");


    get_items_type();


});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    include_once('db_connect.php');

    $switch_number = $_POST["switch-num"];

    switch ($switch_number) {
        case '1':
            get_item_list();
            break;

        case '2':
            get_item();
            break;
    }

    function get_item_list(){

        $get_items = "SELECT * FROM item_type_info";

        $query_get_items = mysql_query($get_items);

        $data = array();

        if(!$query_get_items){


            $data['error'] = die(mysql_error());
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_get_items)){

            $data[] = array( 'item_type_id' => $row['item_type_id'],
                             'item_type' => $row['item_type'] );
        }

        echo json_encode($data);

    }

    function get_item(){
        $item_type_id = $_POST['item_type_id'];

        $get_items = "SELECT * FROM item_info a 
                                LEFT JOIN item_type_info b 
                                ON(a.item_type_id = b.item_type_id) 
                                WHERE a.item_type_id = '$item_type_id' ";

        $query_get_item = mysql_query($get_items);

        $item = array();

        if(!$query_get_item){

            $item['error']=die(mysql_error()); 
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_get_item)){

            $item[] = array( 'item_id' => $row['item_id'],
                             'item_name' => $row['item_name']);
        }

        echo json_encode($item);

    }


?>
```

I used `.on()` as a replacement for `.live()`. I just need to make it work upon the page is loaded the trigger will do change in the select list.

Comment: I beleive it is supposed to be $("#item-types").change(function());

Answer (score 0):

I believe your understanding of the [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function is the issue at hand.  The use of `trigger()` is used to fire an event manually, which you seem to want to have your function fired when your select box is changed.

> Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods
>   are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired
>   manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger()
>   executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event
>   were triggered naturally by the user:

Replace:

```
$("#item-types").trigger("change");


get_items_type();
```

with:

```
$("#item-types").on("change", function(){
    get_items_type();
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pQDjy/

Comment: no it doesnt work.. i tried to alert the value of $("#item-types").val(); and its null i wonder why does the trigger doesnt work

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but the above modification will fire the `get_items_type()` function on the change of the select box. See the fiddle link for a working example.

Comment: the trigger supposedly trigger the change of #item-types then get the value of the then pass it to the ajax

Comment: i found the answer. i put the trigger inside the  get_items_type() before the ending curlybrace of send: